# Sending nulls as parameters to methods in Java

Tags: java, methods, null, parameter-passing, static-analysis

I have a rather simple test case below.  I can send nulls to the constructor with no problems or errors, but when I try to send nulls to a method, it errors out with: `error: incompatible types: <null> cannot be converted to int` (or whatever type is expected).  I'm not exactly sure why this occurs and I've seen in many places where sending nulls is acceptable practice.  In all reality I just need nulls so that I can pump this example into Soot and Spark for static analysis, so the actual parameters sent to the methods are irrelevant other than a semantic necessity for entry points in the Spark-static analysis.

```
public class Test {
    public Test(Object var1, Object var2) {
        //do irrelevant stuff here with var1 and var2
    }

    public void api1(int x, int y) {
        // do irrelevant stuff with x and y
    }

    public List<String> api2(String x, int y, boolean a) {
        // do irrelevant stuff with x, y, and a and return a new ArrayList<String>()
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test usingVars = new Test(1, 2);  // works, compiles and no errors
        Test usingNulls = new Test(null, null); // works, compiles and no errors

        /**
         * usingVars will obviously work and not complain at all
         */
        usingVars.api1(1, 2); // works, compiles and no errors
        usingVars.api2("test", 1, false); // works, compiles and no errors

        /**
         * usingNulls should work, but throws this error on compilation:
         *     error: incompatible types: <null> cannot be converted to int
         */
        usingNulls.api1(null, null); // should work, doesn't compile errors out
        usingNulls.api2(null, null, null); // should work, doesn't compile errors out

    }
}
```

Comment: `null` is not of the same type as `int`. Primitives like `int` cannot be `null`.

Comment: For your `Test(null, null)`, you must have a second two-arg constructor that accepts objects. As others have stated, primitives cannot be set to null. If you want to set the int to a default state, give it a value of 0 and check for that.

Comment: I'm not sure you're using the constructor you think you are with `new Test( null, null)`. ints are primitive types and can't be set to null. See if there is another constructor that takes some sort of objects as parameters; that's the one you're using.

Comment: I edited the code to more appropriately reflect the API that I'm using.  They have nullable objects in the constructor.

Comment: I believe what you're doing by passing an int as an object is creating a boxed copy of the contents of a given int on the heap. This is likely not what you're trying to achieve. If you need a constructor to have two whole numbers, it's better to be specific, otherwise you may experience unexpected results.

Answer (score 6):

primitives, (e.g., `int`s), can't take `null`s. If you absolutely positively have to use a `null` value, you should define your method parameters as the appropriate wrapper class (e.g., `java.lang.Integer` for `int`):

```
public Test(Integer var1, Integer var2) {
    //do irrelevant stuff here with var1 and var2
}

public void api1(Integer x, Integer y) {
    // do irrelevant stuff with x and y
}

public List<String> api2(String x, Integer y, Boolean a) {
    // do irrelevant stuff with x, y, and a and return a new ArrayList<String>()
}
```

Comment: Not sure adding the ability to pass a `null` when this is clearly not valid is a good idea.

Comment: I don't have the option to add a non-primitive parameter to the API, the API is the android source code.  But, because of how I have my API enumerator designed, simply adding a primitive value to the api call is trivial for me.   I'm not actually using the API, at least not in the sense one would think.  My main is used to only generate a call graph.  So what I send the method in regards to parameters is completely irrelevant to the API itself.

Comment: I ended up just altering my logic from indiscriminately making everything null to: `if(number-based primitive){1}else if(boolean){false}else if(char){"a"}else{null}` simple enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In Java you have two types of variables, primitives and references.

A reference can be `null` as it references nothing.  A primitive, such as `int` cannot be `null`, it has to be a number.

If you don't care what the values is you can use `0`, `-1` or `Integer.MIN_VALUE`

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to pass `null` to a method, constructor or otherwise, to a primitive type (e.g. `int`, `short`, `byte`, `float`) because in java you have two type systems, primitives and objects. Primitives can be cast to their object wrappers (e.g. `Integer`, `Short`, `Byte`, `Float`) and be used as objects, so if you *need* to pass null, use `Integer`, not `int`. However the convention in java for passing useless values for `int`s is to use `-1`.